# mulesoft - mongodb - restapi - id value shows extra contents

Tags: mongodb, rest, mule

I have built a RestAPI with MongoDB using Mulesoft.
But the returned data for _id looks odd with a lot of unexpected data which are not from the DB.

How to fix this please?

**Actual**

`[
  {
    "_id": {
      "date": "2018-08-17T15:41:34",
      "processIdentifier": 689,
      "timeSecond": 1534516894,
      "counter": 12813439,
      "timestamp": 1534516894,
      "time": 1534516894000,
      "machineIdentifier": 7769240
    },
    "name": "Armenia",
    "code": "AM"
  }
]`

**Expected**

    `[
        {
            _id: "5b76de9e768c9802b1c3848b",
            name: "Armenia",
            code: "AM"
        }
    ]`

**Mule configuration XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:ldap="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ldap" xmlns:dw="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw" xmlns:metadata="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/metadata" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:mongo="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mongo" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:apikit="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/apikit" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/apikit http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/apikit/current/mule-apikit.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mongo http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mongo/current/mule-mongo.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ldap http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ldap/current/mule-ldap.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="web2-httpListenerConfig" host="0.0.0.0" port="8082" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <apikit:config name="web2-config" raml="web2.raml" consoleEnabled="false" doc:name="Router"/>
    <mongo:config name="Mongo_DB__Configuration" username="user1" password="123" database="mydatabase" host="mongohost" authenticationDatabase="admin" doc:name="Mongo DB: Configuration"/>
    <flow name="web2-main">
        <http:listener config-ref="web2-httpListenerConfig" path="/api/*" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <apikit:router config-ref="web2-config" doc:name="APIkit Router"/>
        <exception-strategy ref="web2-apiKitGlobalExceptionMapping" doc:name="Reference Exception Strategy"/>
    </flow>
    <flow name="web2-console">
        <http:listener config-ref="web2-httpListenerConfig" path="/console/*" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <apikit:console config-ref="web2-config" doc:name="APIkit Console"/>
    </flow>
    <flow name="get:/countries:web2-config">
        <mongo:find-documents config-ref="Mongo_DB__Configuration" collection="payment" doc:name="Mongo DB"/>
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message" metadata:id="517da57f-8f6a-4b76-87fc-ea4462e438b6">
            <dw:input-payload mimeType="application/java" doc:sample="sample_data\json.json"/>
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <set-payload value="#[payload]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    </flow>
    <apikit:mapping-exception-strategy name="web2-apiKitGlobalExceptionMapping">
        <apikit:mapping statusCode="404">
            <apikit:exception value="org.mule.module.apikit.exception.NotFoundException" />
            <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/json" doc:name="Property"/>
            <set-payload value="{ &quot;message&quot;: &quot;Resource not found&quot; }" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        </apikit:mapping>
        <apikit:mapping statusCode="405">
            <apikit:exception value="org.mule.module.apikit.exception.MethodNotAllowedException" />
            <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/json" doc:name="Property"/>
            <set-payload value="{ &quot;message&quot;: &quot;Method not allowed&quot; }" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        </apikit:mapping>
        <apikit:mapping statusCode="415">
            <apikit:exception value="org.mule.module.apikit.exception.UnsupportedMediaTypeException" />
            <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/json" doc:name="Property"/>
            <set-payload value="{ &quot;message&quot;: &quot;Unsupported media type&quot; }" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        </apikit:mapping>
        <apikit:mapping statusCode="406">
            <apikit:exception value="org.mule.module.apikit.exception.NotAcceptableException" />
            <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/json" doc:name="Property"/>
            <set-payload value="{ &quot;message&quot;: &quot;Not acceptable&quot; }" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        </apikit:mapping>
        <apikit:mapping statusCode="400">
            <apikit:exception value="org.mule.module.apikit.exception.BadRequestException" />
            <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/json" doc:name="Property"/>
            <set-payload value="{ &quot;message&quot;: &quot;Bad request&quot; }" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        </apikit:mapping>
    </apikit:mapping-exception-strategy>
</mule>
```

Comment: The actual _id is the default [ObjectID](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) generated by the driver. If you expect a string, you should either set _id as a string explicitly or cast ObjectId to string when you return it.

Comment: @AlexBlex Thx mate can u please help how to do that in Mule?

Comment: Sorry Jay, if I knew Mule I'd post the answer. Check https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.8/dataweave-types#_format. Must be something like `_id:payload._id as :string`

Comment: :-) Thanks mate, will check.